# Give an example of a equicontinuous that does not converge uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, compactness

Give an example of a equicontinuous sequence of functions ($f_n$) over a non-compact set $S\subset\Bbb R^n$ converging pointwise to a function $f$ at each $x\in S$, but $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $f$ over $S$.

I'm really stuck on this problem, and I thought about the cases of $f_n(x) = x^n$ with the domain ($0,1$) or $f_n(x) = sin(nx)$ over non-compact set, but I failed to derive an example. Could someone help me to find an example please? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the functions $f_n(x)=x/n$ over $\Bbb R$, converging non-uniformly to $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Is $\Bbb R$ not compact in this case?

Comment: @user57891, $\Bbb R$ (with the usual topology) isn't compact *in any case*.

Comment: Can you show why this sequence of functions is equicontinuous?

Comment: @user57891 It is perhaps the simplest possible sequence (apart from trivial ones) to show equicontinuity for. Maybe you ought to try it yourself?

Answer (score 2):

$$f_1(x) = 0$$
except in a "hump" between 0 and 1.
$$f_n(x) = f_1(x-n).$$